# Using mpi on my code on C?

Tags: c, mpi, openmp

i have this matrix multiplication on my program :

```
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
        sum=0;
        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
          sum+=a[i*n+k]*b[k*n+j];
        c[j+n*i] = sum;
      }
    }
```

So i optimized it with open Mp so that it can be executed parallel like this :

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nThreads) shared(a,b,c,n) private(temp,i,j,k) // using OMP pragma for parallel
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
        sum=0;
        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
          sum+=a[i*n+k]*b[k*n+j];
        c[j+n*i] = sum;
      }
    }
```

Now i want to implement an MPI too, so it can be really good optimized and parallelized, does anybody know how to implement MPI on my matrix above ? (so it would be openmp+mpi).

p.s : if you find any mistake on my openMP implementation please let me know.

Comment: Several web sites, including computing.llnl.gov, give code which should work with minor modification.

Comment: Adding to @tim18 answer, specifically you can check out this [code](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/samples/C/mpi_mm.c).

Comment: Note that your OpenMP code is incorrect, due to the missing declaration for `sum`. Declare variables as locally as possible, then you don't have these issues. Or work directly on `c` rather than using `sum`.

Comment: @Zulan can't i just put sum under the : private(sum,i,j,k) on omp parallell just like that ?

Comment: @Serenade, yes. That is correct in this case. I strongly favor local declarations as they are much easier to reason about and harder to use incorrectly with OpenMP.